OpenAI API key gives ratelimit error even though api key not used
I am trying to make a chatbot using the Langchain-Openai.I have never done this before. I created a brand new api key, which was never used before. I copied code from the official langchain-openai docs, and the following code:
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_openai import OpenAI

OPENAI_API_KEY = 'sk-proj-...'

template = """Question: {question}

Answer: Let's think step by step."""

prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(template)

llm = OpenAI(openai_api_key="sk-proj-...")

llm_chain = prompt | llm

question = "What NFL team won the Super Bowl in the year Justin Beiber was born?"

llm_chain.invoke(question)

It is giving this very long error:
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\Users\Acer\OneDrive\Documents\VS_Code\Python\ai\Langchain-Openai.py", line 25, in <module>
    llm_chain.invoke(question)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 2399, in invoke
    input = step.invoke(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\llms.py", line 276, in invoke
    self.generate_prompt(
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\llms.py", line 633, in generate_prompt
    return self.generate(prompt_strings, stop=stop, callbacks=callbacks, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\llms.py", line 803, in generate
    output = self._generate_helper(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\llms.py", line 670, in _generate_helper
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\llms.py", line 657, in _generate_helper
    self._generate(
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\langchain_openai\llms\base.py", line 350, in _generate
    response = self.client.create(prompt=_prompts, **params)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\openai\_utils\_utils.py", line 277, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\openai\resources\completions.py", line 528, in create
    return self._post(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 1240, in post
    return cast(ResponseT, self.request(cast_to, opts, stream=stream, stream_cls=stream_cls))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 921, in request
    return self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 1005, in _request
    return self._retry_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 1053, in _retry_request
    return self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 1005, in _request
    return self._retry_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 1053, in _retry_request
    return self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 1020, in _request
    raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
openai.RateLimitError: Error code: 429 - {'error': {'message': 'You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details. For more information on this error, read the docs: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors.', 'type': 'insufficient_quota', 'param': None, 'code': 'insufficient_quota'}}

I even checked the openai api key usage website and it is not showing anything.
All of the code is from the Langchain-Openai docs.
Am I doing something wrong?
EDIT:
As @trazoM pointed out, the code works just fine but apparently I just needed to make a new key and link a credit card. Thanks @trazoM!


Get a new api key
Add your credit card details


@trazoM Do i have to link my credit card details to use even the free usage they are giving us? Because Im a student and dont have a credit card.

You code works fine for me. I have my credit card details in already.

@RokBenko Yes, it does, but it didn't appear when stackoverflow was asking me if my question was similar to other questions probably because it was closed.

As @trazoM pointed out, the code works just fine but apparently I just needed to make a new key and link a credit card. Thanks @trazoM! Writing this to make this question appeared as answered.
